# AWS Use STS to generate dynamic credentials for Lambda to invoke another Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sts

Struggling with a problem here.  Node.js.  I need to generate temporary credentials using STS from a dynamically generated temporary, highly specific reduced scope role.  I then need to use the STS credentials to invoke another Lambda so that control can be passed to the new Lambda, which runs under the reduced temporary scope.  SaaS factory style but where we need to limit the Lambda scope itself rather than using the credentials in individual service calls to things like S3 and DynamoDB.  i.e. The Lambda to which control is passed, is invoked with the STS credentials, which automatically limit scope of the code the new Lambda executes so that any calls the developer might make are already restricted.

Using code pretty much as below:

```
let policy = require('./clientPolicy.json');
let sts = new AWS.STS();
let stsParams = {
    RoleArn: process.env.clientWrapperRole,         //primary execution role
    RoleSessionName: `cws-${clientWrapperSession}`,
    Policy: policyString,                           //generated policy
    DurationSeconds: 900
}
let stsResult = await sts.assumeRole(stsParams).promise();
let clientWrapperCred = stsResult.Credentials;
let clientLambdaParams = {
    FunctionName: process.env.clientWrapper, /* required */
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(clientLambdaPayload)
};

let clientLambda = new AWS.Lambda({ credentials: clientWrapperCred });
let clientResult = await clientLambda.invoke(clientLambdaParams).promise();
```

Logging shows that the STS call functions correctly, generating credentials against a role that has wide scope, including the ability to call Lambda, which has a service trust to lambda.amazonaws.com and also the role principal of the calling Lambda.  The client policy includes scope equivalent to Lambda basic auths, plus allows invoke against the new Lambda.

clientLambda declaration occurs ok but execution at let clientResult... hangs for the maximum Lambda timeout before returning an error response: {"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"}

If I don't use the STS credentials, but just invoke the Lambda like this:

```
let clientLambda = new AWS.Lambda();
let clientResult = await clientLambda.invoke(clientLambdaParams).promise();
```

...then everything works OK.

Anyone got any ideas?  Normally I'd just scope down the execution role attached to the Lambda to be called, but in this case I need to dynamically adjust the scope depending on the payload being passed like a SaaS factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at the SDK docs suggests that the `Credentials` returned from assumeRole is a map while the `credentials` option provided to the `AWS.Lambda()` client constructor is of type `AWS.Credentials` with different property names.

So, try creating `clientWrapperCred` like this:

```
let clientWrapperCred = {
  accessKeyId: stsResult.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: stsResult.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: stsResult.Credentials.SessionToken
}
```

I've verified this works correctly using the following code:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

get_assumed_credentials = async () => {
  const sts = new AWS.STS();

  const stsParams = {
    RoleArn: ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN,
    RoleSessionName: 'cws-1234',
    DurationSeconds: 900,
  };

  const stsResult = await sts.assumeRole(stsParams).promise();

  const clientWrapperCred = {
    accessKeyId: stsResult.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: stsResult.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: stsResult.Credentials.SessionToken,
  };

  return clientWrapperCred;
};

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const creds = await get_assumed_credentials();

    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda(creds);

    const lambda_params = {
      FunctionName: INVOKED_LAMBDA_FUNC,
      Payload: JSON.stringify({ id: 42, source: "hitchhiker" }),
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
    };

    const lambda_rsp = await lambda.invoke(lambda_params).promise();
    console.log("Lambda rsp:\n" + lambda_rsp);
    console.log("Lambda json:\n" + JSON.stringify(lambda_rsp));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

The Lambda function's execution role with EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN was as follows:

- Trust policy: allows sts:AssumeRole from lambda.amazonaws.com
- AWS Managed policy: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
- Inline policy: allows it to assume ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN, as follows:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
                "Resource": "ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The assumed role with ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN was as follows:

- Trust policy: allows sts:AssumeRole from EXECUTION_ROLE_ARN
- AWS Managed policy: AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
- Inline policy: allows it to invoke INVOKED_LAMBDA_FUNC, as follows:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "Resource": "INVOKED_LAMBDA_FUNC"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And the INVOKED_LAMBDA_FUNC had an AWS Managed policy of AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole (for logging purposed) and the function simply prints its received event payload (`{ id: 42, source: "hitchhiker" }`) and returns a hello world response.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, thanks for looking.  I did try this but just got the same error.  I even used CodeWhisperer which suggested the way I described.  I started to wonder if, because the generated credential is effectively a user, that the role being used should also have an iam:passRole permission as well as the trusts but I've not had time to try that out yet.    If only the error message had some actual detail of what was wrong!

Comment: I verified that this code works correctly where the Lambda function invocation is executed using credentials associated with the assumed role.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, thanks for your help.  What do you have in your role 'SOME_ROLE_ARN_HERE'?  And what execution role do you have configured against the deployed 'SOME_LAMBDA_FUNCNAME_HERE'?  I'm wondering if there's something conflicting in the way my submitted STS role and the role that my target Lambda was originally configured with.  Could you share those details with me please?  It would help me to debug.

Comment: Hi Jarmod, marking your answer as correct.  It looks like it's one of the execution roles, either the calling Lambda or more likely the target Lambda that is the problem.  I retried your solution but this time using, essentially using AdminFullAcess roles usable by account root as well as the service principal as a test.  Works with these roles and just the specified keys as per your code.  I'd still like to know what you have in your execution roles and the role you were using with SOME_ROLE_HERE though in order to confirm though.  Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Added policy details.

Comment: Thanks Jarmod.  Although I had the trusts correctly defined, the additional auths assigned were limiting scope too much.  Although the AWS docs imply that the whole credential from STS can just be passed to the lambda service, in fact the Lambda service also only expects those specific keys.  Moral of the story seems to be to start with broad auths and scope down later, and only pass the Lambda service call the least information needed!